# Flutter Firebase Phone Auth Ios - Unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x86614e791064ac50

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm developing a app with flutter for ios and android. But when i run the app for ios on real device this error appears and I can't solve it because I don't understand much about debugging errors in xcode.

The Error on Xcode is:

```
-[NSTaggedPointerString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x86614e791064ac50
```

and then the app crash.

This error does not appear in the ios simulator. Only when I install the app on a real ios device.

This is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pinput/pinput.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:oklevafood/providers/definicoes_prov.dart';

class Otp extends StatefulWidget {
  const Otp({super.key, required this.tel});
  final dynamic tel;

  @override
  State<Otp> createState() => _OtpState();
}

class _OtpState extends State<Otp> {

  final defaultPinTheme = PinTheme(
    width: 56,
    height: 56,
    textStyle: const TextStyle(
        fontSize: 20,
        color: Color.fromRGBO(30, 60, 87, 1),
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      border: Border.all(color: const Color.fromRGBO(91, 104, 114, 1)),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
    ),
  );

  dynamic codigoVerificacao;

  _verificarTel(dynamic tel) async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: tel,
        verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
          try {
            await FirebaseAuth.instance
                .signInWithCredential(credential)
                .then((value) async {
              if (value.user != null) {
                Provider.of<DefinicoesProv>(context, listen: false)
                    .setDefinicoesIntro(1);
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/');
              }
            });
          } catch (e) {
            print('Código invalido');
          }

          print('Verification Completed');
        },
        verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException exception) {
          print(exception.message);
        },
        codeSent: (verificationId, forceResendingToken) {
          setState(() {
            //codigoVerificacao = verificationId;
          });
        },
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: ((verificationId) {
          setState(() {
            //codigoVerificacao = verificationId;
          });
        }),
        timeout: const Duration(seconds: 60));
  }

 

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _verificarTel(widget.tel);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //final routArgs =
    //ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as Map<String, dynamic>;

    return Scaffold(
      //key: _scaffoldkey,
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.4,
            child: Image.asset(
              'assets/images/otp.gif',
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: const Text(
              'Insira código que enviamos a por SMS',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(18),
            child: Pinput(
              length: 6,
              defaultPinTheme: defaultPinTheme,
              focusedPinTheme: defaultPinTheme.copyDecorationWith(
                border:
                    Border.all(color: const Color.fromRGBO(114, 178, 238, 1)),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              ),
              submittedPinTheme: defaultPinTheme.copyWith(
                decoration: defaultPinTheme.decoration?.copyWith(
                  color: const Color.fromRGBO(212, 213, 214, 1),
                ),
              ),
              
              pinputAutovalidateMode: PinputAutovalidateMode.onSubmit,
              showCursor: true,
              onCompleted: (pin) async {
                try {
                  await FirebaseAuth.instance
                      .signInWithCredential(PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
                          verificationId: codigoVerificacao, smsCode: pin))
                      .then((value) async {
                    if (value.user != null) {
                      Provider.of<DefinicoesProv>(context, listen: false)
                          .setDefinicoesIntro(1);
                      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/');
                    }
                  });
                } catch (e) {
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                      content: Row(
                    children: [
                      Icon(
                        Icons.error,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                          child: Text(
                              'Código invalido. Insira o código correto da SMS'))
                    ],
                  )));
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(28.0),
            child: FilledButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
              child: const Text(
                'Voltar',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?